# DropDownListFor appears to populate magically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Stumbled upon this dropdown:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.RabbitId, null, "Please Select Bunny...", new {@class = "Wibble"})`

The SelectList parameter is being passed null, yet it still appears to populate with a full list of Bunnys.

I suspect it's because c, the Model, is an Entity (the author is using an Entity as the model). But I can't be sure. I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere.

I'm surprised it works with the SelectList being `null`. Any ideas?

Comment: is it loaded in javascript?

Comment: nope, there are no references to it on the page.

Comment: if `null` is provided as the select list, then there won't be any records. there must be something in javascript that's loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Very badly documented in MSDN but I have found the answer. If null is specified, 
the Html.DropDownList will look in the ViewData (ViewBag) for an entry with the same key that contains a SelectList of the data.

I hope this helps someone in the future. It's quite unintuitive.

Comment: Html.DropDownListFor() does not use ViewData but Html.DropDownList() does. You should edit your question or answer to clarify as those are two seperate helpers, with the latter being used mostly in older versions of MVC.

Comment: Incorrect, the code I have is DropDownListFor and it is pulling it from the ViewBag.